# Queue implementation in ES6

Tags: javascript, queue

Here's my Queue implementation in ES6,

```
class Queue{
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }
    offer(item){
        const p = new Node(item);
        if(!this.head){
            this.head = p;
            this.tail = p;
            return;
        }
        this.tail.next = p;
        this.tail = p;

    }
    poll(){
        const item = this.head;
        this.head = this.head.next;
        return item;

    }
    peek(){
        return this.head.val;
    }
    isEmpty(){
        return this.head === null;
    }
}
```

Please review on all fronts.

Comment: Why is `p` assigned to both `this.head` and `this.tail`? What is the  expected result?

Comment: If that's the first node it's both the head and tail. The next node onwards offer moves the tail and poll moves the head. If I had one node and didn't assign both head and tail to it, the offer wouldn't work on the second node, since there's no tail defined yet.

Comment: Did you have a class definition for `Node`? If so, please [edit] your post to include it... otherwise this code appears broken, revealing an error after instantiating a Queue object and calling the `offer` method: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`

Answer (score 3):

### Does not work, can be mutated

You did not even test this object. Please take time to make sure the code you put up for review is at least working next time. :)

#### Bugs.

You don't tests if `head` is defined for the functions `peek`, and `poll`.

```
const q = new Queue();
q.peek(); // throws TypeError cannot read property val of null
q.poll(); // throws TypeError cannot read property next of null
```

Can only Get one object from the `Queue` per group of `offer` calls

```
q.offer("A");
q.offer("B");
q.poll(); // return "A"
q.peek(); // throws TypeError cannot read property val of null
q.poll(); // throws TypeError cannot read property next of null


// OR
q.offer("A");
q.offer("B");
q.poll(); // return "A"
q.offer("C");
q.poll(); // return "C"  What happened to "B"
```

#### Mutation

You have not encapsulated the object state and thus can be mutated in many ways to produce unexpected behaviours

```
const q = new Queue()
q.offer("foo");
q.head.tail = q.head;  
while(!q.isEmpty()) { console.log(q.poll().val) } // never stops

// and
q.head = undefined;
q.isEmpty(); // incorrectly returns false
```

### Bloated

The property `Queue.tail` does nothing and is just noise.

I am guessing you wanted to use it to make `offer` quicker without needing to step all the way down the links from `head` but that will require a doubly linked list.

You could just use an array.